# XSLT: for-each in for-each not working?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

i've a XML file which looks like:

```
<VersionHistory>
  <Release Version="0.0.1" Date="27/1/2011">
    <NewFeature>foo</NewFeature>
    <BugFix>some text</BugFix>
    <BugFix>some text</BugFix>
    <BugFix Ticket="12004">some text</BugFix>
  </Release>
  <Release Version="0.0.2" Date="15/2/2011">
    <NewFeature>foobar</NewFeature>
    <BugFix>some more text</BugFix>
    <BugFix>some more text</BugFix>
    <BugFix Ticket="12001">some more text</BugFix>
  </Release>
</VersionHistory>
```

Now my XSLT looks like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="VersionHistory/Release">
      <xsl:sort select="@Version"/>
  <ul>
        <li>
          <h3>New Feature<br/></h3>
          <xsl:for-each select="NewFeature">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="NewFeature"/>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </li>
         <h3>
            Fixed<br/>
          </h3>
            <xsl:for-each select="BugFix">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="BugFix"/>
                  </p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </li>
...
```

My problem is, that the 2nd for-each which goes through the BugFixes creates the amout of list items the xml contains of this element.. but i dont get the text which is between . Why?
How can i fix this?

this is not only for BugFix of course.. its for all this elements like BugFix, NewFeature (there are some more.. i haven't list here)

greets

Comment: Don't use `for-each` - use templates.

Comment: Can there be multiple New Featue per Release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `for-each` you select `NewFeature`, then in the `value-of`, you are calling the value of a *child-node* called `NewFeature`:

```
      <xsl:for-each select="NewFeature">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="NewFeature"/>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Since `NewFeature` doesn't *contain* a `NewFeature` node, you see nothing.

This would work (selecting the *current* node in the `for-each` loop):

```
      <xsl:for-each select="NewFeature">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

But a better option would be to use a template (which you should to with *all* of your `for-each` loops):

```
<xsl:template match="NewFeature">
  <ul>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>
```